# Error: No database Found in Flask

Tags: python, flask

This is a basic login form I am creating in Flask, but this error arises on the registration page.

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')
```

I am getting an error of no database found. What is the error? It is not connecting to the database. I have used MySQL for Python 3.6:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, 
logging, request
from data import Articles  
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, 
validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt


app = Flask(__name__)

# db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','','myflaskapp')
#Config Mysql
app.config['MySQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MySQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MySQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MySQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MySQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

mysql = MySQL(app)

Articles = Articles()

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/link')
def link():
   return render_template("link.html")

@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    return render_template('articles.html', articles =  Articles)

@app.route('/articles/<string:id>/')
def article(id):
    return render_template('article.html' , id=id)

class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name',[validators.Length(min=2,max = 50)])
    username = StringField('Username',[validators.Length(min = 4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('Password',[
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm',message="Passwords do not match")
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')


 @app.route('/register', methods =['GET','POST'])
 def register():
     form = RegisterForm(request.form)
     if request.method == 'POST'and form.validate():
         name = form.name.data
         email = form.email.data
         username = form.username.data
         password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

         cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

         cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name,username,email,password) 
         VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,username,email,password))

         mysql.connection.commit()
         cur.close()

         flash("You are nor registered and login", "success")
         redirect(url_for('index'))

         return render_template('register.html', form = form)
      return render_template('register.html', form = form)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.secret_key = 'secret123'
      app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: have you tried to connect to the database from the terminal? Maybe your local db server is not started
`mysql -u root -p`

Also, maybe the database with name `myflaskapp` is not created at all?

Comment: I have created the databse in xampp. and the databse is created.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration parameters at the top of your code. Note that `userpass` must consist of both the db username and password. `socket` is the location of the mysql socket file in the XAMPP directory.

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some secret string here'

userpass = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@'
basedir  = '127.0.0.1'
dbname   = '/nameofdatabase'
socket   = '?unix_socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
dbname   = dbname + socket
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = userpass + basedir + dbname

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
```